# Do not validate hidden fields jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with a dropdown list. Based on the selection in the dropdown , I should hide few input fields. When I perform validation , I should not do it for hidden fields. I have written a lengthy code for this which is working fine. But I am sure there is a better way to do this. Please let me know if any.

If you select "A" from Dropdown, hide "**Due Date**" from form, if you select "B", hide "**Away Whse**", for any other option selected hide both "Date" and "Away Whse". Input fields - "**Device Id**" and "**Reason Code**" are required in all cases.

Working Code:
jQuery:

```
$('#lockForm select[name="Key"]').change(function () {
               var selectedOption = $('#lockForm select[name="Key"] option:selected').val();
                if (selectedOption == 'A' ) $('.datepicker,.ticket').hide();
                else $('.datepicker,.ticket').show();
                if (selectedOption == 'B' ) $('.awayWhse').hide();
                else $('.awayWhse').show();
                if (selectedOption == 'C' || selectedOption == 'D') $('.hidden').hide();
                else $('.hidden').show();
    });
$('#btnLock').click(function() {
         var selectedOption = $('#lockForm select[name="Key"] option:selected').val();
         if($.trim($('.deviceIdLock').val()) == ''){
            $('#area21').html("Device Id is a required field.");
         }else if($.trim($('.reasonCode').val()) == 'NONE'){
            $('#area21').html("Reason Code is a required field.");
         }else if (selectedOption == 'A' ){
             if($.trim($('.awayWhse1').val()) == 'NONE')    $('#area21').html("Away Warehouse is a required field.");
             else $('#lockForm').submit();
         }else if (selectedOption == 'B' ){
             if($.trim($('#datepicker').val()) == '')   $('#area21').html("Due date is a required field.");
             else $('#lockForm').submit();
         }else{
            $('#lockForm').submit();
         }
    });
```

html:

```
<form:form method="post" id="lockForm" modelAttribute="adminTransaction" action="/DeviceManager/admin/lock">
        <div align=center class="plErroMessage" id="area21">${serverError2}</div> 
        <div class="plSuccessMessage" id="area22">${serverSuccess2}</div> 
        <div>
            <div class="plLabelSearch">Device Id:</div> 
            <div class="plinput"><form:input path="deviceId" class="deviceIdLock" size="29"/></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="plLabelSearch">Reason Code:</div> 
                <div class="plselect">
            <form:select path="Key" class="reasonCode">
            <form:option value="NONE" label="------- Select One -------" />
            <form:options items="${reasonList}" itemValue="reasonCode" itemLabel="reasonDesc"/>
            </form:select>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden" >
        <div class="awayWhse">
            <div class="plLabelSearch">Away Whse:</div> 
            <div class="plselect">
            <form:select path="awayWarehouse" class="awayWhse1">
            <form:option value="NONE" label="------- Select One -------" />
            <form:options items="${homeWhseList}" itemValue="warehouseCode" itemLabel="warehouseCode"/>
            </form:select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="datepicker">
            <div class="plLabelSearch">Due Date:</div> 
            <div class="plinput"><form:input id="datepicker" path="dueDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="plLabelSearch">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="plinput"><a id="btnLock" class="abutton">Lock</a></div>
            <div class="plinput"><a id="btnCancel2" class="abutton">Cancel</a></div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in CodeReview

Comment: where can I post code review questions?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/